# UriBuilder doesn't work if parameter's value happens to look like a template?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Trying to use this UriBuilder class to create an endpoint for my Http client to hit https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/uribuilder

```
        String key = "b4o3h4{g}fghg3";
        String uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(getUriForName(name))
            .queryParam("name", name)
            .queryParam("key", key)
            .build();
```

But I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
The template variable 'g' has no value
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The template variable 'g' has no value
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate$1ValuesFromArrayStrategy.valueFor(UriTemplate.java:996)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.resolveTemplate(UriTemplate.java:682)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createUriComponent(UriTemplate.java:1006)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURIWithStringValues(UriTemplate.java:946)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURIWithStringValues(UriTemplate.java:882)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURI(UriTemplate.java:847)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder._build(JerseyUriBuilder.java:890)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.build(JerseyUriBuilder.java:807)
```

This is due to my query parameter's value just happening to look like a template. Is there a way for me to pass this value in if that's my actual value and not a template?

Comment: Have you tried to url encode it?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yea I've tried url encoding it before passing it to the UriBuilder. But the UriBuilder will try encoding it again won't it?

Comment: _"URI template names and delimiters are never encoded but their values are encoded when a URI is built"_ - I don't know if by delimiter, they mean curly brackets.

Comment: Yea I'm not sure how that works at all.